# If function return true, then execute a command in if condition

Tags: javascript

Here is code below.
Now I want to execute a special command **if function return true.**
Whenever I call function under "if", the special command always doing his work.

```js
// You are trapped. Don't move, it'll be painful.
// Attack ogres only when they're within reach.
// This function checks if the enemy is in your attack range.
// The function returns a boolean value:  true or false
function inAttackRange(enemy) {
    var distance = hero.distanceTo(enemy);
    // Almost all swords have attack range of 3.
    if (distance <= 3) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
while (true) {
    // Find the nearest enemy and store it in a variable.
    var enemy = hero.findNearestEnemy();
    // Call inAttackRange(enemy), with the enemy as the argument
    // and save the result in the variable canAttack.
    var canAttack = inAttackRange(enemy);
    // If the result stored in canAttack is true, then attack!
    if (canAttack) {       
        
            hero.attack(enemy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **where** would you like to insert *"a special command"*?

Comment: special command is hero.attack(enemy); and this will execute only when the function return true.

Comment: Where? in if condition

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a syntax error. Here's the working script (may not work because some functions and vars like "o.findNearestEnemy()" or "hero" do not exist)

```js
// You are trapped. Don't move, it'll be painful.
// Attack ogres only when they're within reach.
// This function checks if the enemy is in your attack range.
// The function returns a boolean value:  true or false
function inAttackRange(enemy) {
    var distance = hero.distanceTo(enemy);
    // Almost all swords have attack range of 3.
    if (distance <= 3) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
while (true) {
    // Find the nearest enemy and store it in a variable.
    var enemy = hero.findNearestEnemy();
    // Call inAttackRange(enemy), with the enemy as the argument
    // and save the result in the variable canAttack.
    var canAttack = inAttackRange(enemy);
    // If the result stored in canAttack is true, then attack!
    if (canAttack) {       
        
            hero.attack(enemy);
    }
}
```